# Converting a Spark's DataFrame column to List[String] in Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am working on [Movie Lens](http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) data set. In one the the `csv` files, the data is structured as:

`movieId` `movieTitle` `genres`

and `genres` again is a list of `|` separated values, the field is nullable.

I am trying to get a unique list of all the `genres` so that I can rearrange the data as following:

`movieId` `movieTitle` `genre1` `genre2` `...` `genreN`

and a row, which has `genre` as `genre1 | genre2` will look like:

`1` `Title1` `1` `1` `0` `...` `0`

So far, I have been able to read the `csv` file using the following code:

```
val conf         = new SparkConf().setAppName(App.name).setMaster(App.sparkMaster)
val context      = new SparkContext(conf)
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                   .appName(App.name)
                   .config("header", "true")
                   .config(conf = conf)
                   .getOrCreate()

val movieFrame: DataFrame = sparkSession.read.csv(moviesPath)
```

If I try something like:

```
movieFrame.rdd.map(row ⇒ row(2).asInstanceOf[String]).collect()
```

Then I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.babbupandey.ReadData$$anonfun$1
```

Then, in addition, I tried providing the schema explicitly using the following code:

```
val moviesSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("movieId", StringType, nullable = true),
                                                        StructField("title", StringType, nullable = true),
                                                        StructField("genres", StringType, nullable = true)))
```

and tried:

```
val movieFrame: DataFrame = sparkSession.read.schema(moviesSchema).csv(moviesPath)
```

and then I got the same exception.

Is there any way in which I can the set of `genres` as a `List` or a `Set` so I can further massage the data into the desired format? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I got the set of genres:

```
val genreList: Array[String] = for (row <- movieFrame.select("genres").collect) yield row.getString(0)
val genres: Array[String] =  for {
        g ← genreList
        genres ← g.split("\\|")
    } yield genres
val genreSet : Set[String] = genres.toSet
```

Comment: this is great!!

Answer (score -1):

This worked to give an Array[Array[String]]

```
    val genreLst = movieFrame.select("genres").rdd.map(r =>     r(0).asInstanceOf[String].split("\\|").map(_.toString).distinct).collect()
```

To get Array[String]

```
    val genres = genreLst.flatten
```

or

```
    val genreLst = movieFrame.select("genres").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String].split("\\|").map(_.toString).distinct).collect().flatten
```